# UserRoles table with no PK

Tags: sql-server, database-schema, composite-primary-key

I have the following tables (among others):

1. Users
2. Departments
3. Roles
4. UserRoles

The `UserRoles` table has the following fields:

1. UserId
2. RoleId
3. DepartmentId (NULL)

The idea here is I can give a user a specific role, for specific department(s), if the `DepartmentId` is NULL, then this role applies to all departments.

The problem here I cannot make a composite primary key out of the three fields in the `UserRoles` table since the `DepartmentId` is nullable.

Should I just go with a unique index without a primary key since I cannot have a primary key for the first two columns only (that will prevent the user from having the same role to multiple departments), or should I change the whole structure to something else (any ideas will be appreciated).

Answer (score 0):

I would make DepartmentID not null and assign a value of 0 to symbolize all departments. This will help you both in creating a PK and in queries where now you can simply say where DepartmentID = 0 instead of where DepartmentID is null.

Comment: I cannot set it to 0 unless I remove the FK to the Departments table.

Comment: you can disable a constraint temporarily with a ALTER TABLE < <TableName> NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all, recreate the PK and reenable the constraint.